# Flask REST-API within an alpine docker container memory leak

Tags: python, docker, flask, memory-leaks, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to find a kind of memory leak in my flask REST-API for a few days now without any relevant progress.

I have a flask REST-API using a mysql database (packages like SQLAlchemy, connexion and marshmallow). It is available via a docker container which have a base image from alpine:latest.

The main problem i have: with every request to the REST-API the memory usage of the docker container increases and the memory is not released. The API do not cache the results.

Here is the code from the server.py (the main program of the RESt-API):

```
"""
Main module of the server file
"""

# 3rd party moudles

# local modules
import config

# Get the application instance
connex_app = config.connex_app

# Read the swagger.yml file to configure the endpoints
connex_app.add_api("swagger_2.0.yml")

# create a URL route in our application for "/"
@connex_app.route("/")
def home():
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connex_app.run(debug=True)
```

and the config file:

```
import os

import connexion
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from memory_profiler import memory_usage


basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Create the Connexion application instance
connex_app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir=basedir)

# Get the underlying Flask app instance
app = connex_app.app
CORS(app)

# Configure the SQLAlchemy part of the app instance
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql://root:somepassword@someHostId/sponge"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False


@app.after_request
def add_header(response):
    #response.cache_control.no_store = True
    if 'Cache-Control' not in response.headers:
        response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=0'
    print(memory_usage(-1, interval=.2, timeout=1), "after request")
    return response


# Create the SQLAlchemy db instance
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Initialize Marshmallow
ma = Marshmallow(app)
```

An example for an endpoint you can see here:

```
from flask import abort
import models

def read(disease_name=None):
    """
       This function responds to a request for /sponge/dataset/?disease_name={disease_name}
       with one matching entry to the specifed diesease_name

       :param disease_name:   name of the dataset to find (if not given, all available datasets will be shown)
       :return:            dataset matching ID
       """

    if disease_name is None:
        # Create the list of people from our data
        data = models.Dataset.query \
            .all()
    else:
        # Get the dataset requested
        data = models.Dataset.query \
            .filter(models.Dataset.disease_name.like("%" + disease_name + "%")) \
            .all()

    # Did we find a dataset?
    if len(data) > 0:
        # Serialize the data for the response
        return models.DatasetSchema(many=True).dump(data).data
    else:
        abort(404, 'No data found for name: {disease_name}'.format(disease_name=disease_name))
```

I tried to find the memory leak within the code with the memory_profiler tool, but since the same behavior (increasing memory usage of the docker container at each request) can be observed at each REST-API endpoint.

Can anyone explain what is happening oder have an idea of how i can fix the caching problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is fixed. Actually it was no problem. The docker stats memory usage increases due to implementation of python. If the rest-api request is multiple GB big, then python allocates a certain percentage of that used memory and do not free it immidiatly. So the peaks at 500 GB were after a relly great answer. I added to the API endpoints a fixed limit and and hint for the user if he exceeds this limit he should download  the whole database as a zip fornat and work locally with it.